# Autocomplete newest file

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a process which creates text files whose filenames are based on the timestamp of their moment of creation:

```
$ ls
1378971222.txt
1378971254.txt
1378971482.txt
1378971488.txt
1378972089.txt
1378972140.txt
1378972141.txt
1378972153.txt
1378972155.txt
1378972241.txt
```

**How might I auto-complete the filename of the latest created file**, i.e. the file with the latest mtime? There is no way to use Tab-completion for these files as almost every character in the filename is shared with another file. I am hoping to find a shortcut (such as `Alt .` which autocompletes the last argument of last command). I have managed to concoct the following alias which is great for `VIM`, but I would love to know if a general-purpose shortcut exists that I could use with `kde-open`, `sqlite3`, and other applications.

```
alias lastest="vim `ls -t | grep -vE "^total [0-9]*$" | head -n1`"
```

Comment: http://www.humbug.in/2010/custom-key-bindings-keyboard-shortcuts-in-bash/

Comment: Having read all that, the question seems to have no satisfactory answer yet on how to have a keyboard shortcut to insert latest filepath (a la bash completion, and hopefully, also cycle through in chronological order) in the bash shell?

Comment: @RomanSusi: This closest answer is by Weidenrinde, but it only inserts a literal `$(ls -t|head -1)` into the line. Therefore, no cycling.  In absence of a satisfactory answer, I accepted the answer which taught me the most and provides the most utility.

Comment: Sure. It just occured to me it could be a cool shell feature, and wondered why nobody yet implemented it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the bash completion "_filedir" function to allow tab completion with the last filename.  Here is a script that you can `source` that does this:

```
#!/bin/sh

_filedir_newest()
{
    local parent="$1"
    if [ "${#parent}" -gt "0" ]; then
        parent="$(compgen -d -- ${1:0:-1})/"
    fi
    newest=$(bash -c "ls -tr $parent | tail -n 1")
    echo "$parent$newest"
} # _filedir_newest()

_filedir()
{
    local IFS=$'\n'

    _tilde "$cur" || return

    local -a toks
    local x reset
    local newest=0

    reset=$(shopt -po noglob); set -o noglob
    toks=( $(compgen -d -- "$cur") )
    IFS=' '; $reset; IFS=$'\n'

    if [[ "$1" != -d ]]; then
        local quoted
        if [[ "$cur" = "?" ]] || [[ "${cur: -2}" = "/?" ]]; then
            cur="${cur:0:-1}"
            newest=1
        fi
        _quote_readline_by_ref "$cur" quoted

        # Munge xspec to contain uppercase version too
        # http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/15294/focus=15306
        local xspec=${1:+"!*.@($1|${1^^})"}
        reset=$(shopt -po noglob); set -o noglob
        toks+=( $(compgen -f -X "$xspec" -- $quoted) )
        IFS=' '; $reset; IFS=$'\n'

        # Try without filter if it failed to produce anything and configured to
        [[ -n ${COMP_FILEDIR_FALLBACK:-} && -n "$1" && ${#toks[@]} -lt 1 ]] && {
            reset=$(shopt -po noglob); set -o noglob
            toks+=( $(compgen -f -- $quoted) )
            IFS=' '; $reset; IFS=$'\n'
        }
    fi

    if [[ ${#toks[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
        # 2>/dev/null for direct invocation, e.g. in the _filedir unit test
        compopt -o filenames 2>/dev/null
        if [[ $newest -eq 1 ]]; then
            COMPREPLY+=( $(_filedir_newest "$cur") )
        else
            COMPREPLY+=( "${toks[@]}" )
        fi
    fi
} # _filedir()

_filedir_xspec()
{
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return

    _tilde "$cur" || return

    local IFS=$'\n' xspec=${_xspecs[${1##*/}]} tmp
    local -a toks
    local newest=0

    if [[ "$cur" = "?" ]] || [[ "${cur: -2}" = "/?" ]]; then
        cur="${cur:0:-1}"
        newest=1
    fi

    toks=( $(
        compgen -d -- "$(quote_readline "$cur")" | {
        while read -r tmp; do
            printf '%s\n' $tmp
        done
        }
        ))

    # Munge xspec to contain uppercase version too
    # http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/15294/focus=15306
    eval xspec="${xspec}"
    local matchop=!
    if [[ $xspec == !* ]]; then
        xspec=${xspec#!}
        matchop=@
    fi
    xspec="$matchop($xspec|${xspec^^})"

    toks+=( $(
        eval compgen -f -X "'!$xspec'" -- "\$(quote_readline "\$cur")" | {
        while read -r tmp; do
            [[ -n $tmp ]] && printf '%s\n' $tmp
        done
        }
        ))

    if [[ ${#toks[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
        compopt -o filenames
        if [[ $newest -eq 1 ]]; then
            COMPREPLY=( $(_filedir_newest "$cur") )
        else
            COMPREPLY=( "${toks[@]}" )
        fi
    fi
} # _filedir_xspec()
```

It can be added to your `~/.bashrc` like so (replace `/path/to/the/script` as appropriate), so that it applies to all bash sessions:

```
source /path/to/the/script/_filedir.sh
```

Once installed, '?' is used as the special indicator for the last file in a directory, for example:

```
eog ~/Downloads/?<TAB>
```

becomes (in one instance):

```
eog ~/Downloads/Sunscreen\ Permission\ -\ ToddlerPrimaryElementary.pdf
```

This technique will work with any directory, since it is integrated with the bash completion system, rather than just reporting the most recent file in the current directory. I use this frequently to move recently downloaded files from my browser into the folder for whatever project I'm actively working on (`mv ~/Downloads/?<TAB> .`).

**Updated 2021-10-27:** Now works with `_filedir_xspec` bash autocomplete routines as well
**Updated 2021-11-09:** Fixed a bug when operating on the current directory from last update.

Comment: This is terrific, thank you.

Comment: This is a great answer, but interestingly it does not work with all commands! It works with e.g. `ls` and `file`, but not with `vim`. Have you any idea why that may be?

Comment: @dotancohen Yes, that's because vim uses a different version of this routine called `_filedir_xspec` (see `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`).  Try this and, if it works for you, I'll add it to the answer: https://gist.github.com/compholio/dbef636fb52b72a67b3afa5ed6f34675

Comment: Thank you! With the new addition, this answer is the best answer on the page.

Comment: @dotancohen No problem, I've now updated the answer to include both routines.

Answer (score 7):

You can [easily configure this in `zsh`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-file_002dsort_002c-completion-style), e.g. with something like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' file-sort date
```

(you can also change the line such that this style is only used for certain file name patterns)

[`zsh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) is very similar to bash, you could probably call it a superset of bash - feature-/usage-wise.

But perhaps bash has a similar feature.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. For a few reasons I prefer not to move to `zsh` but if I ever do, I have this bookmarked!

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `zsh`!

Answer (score 7):

Just remove the `vim` from the alias. Do something like this:

```
alias latest='ls -tr | tail -n 1'
```

You can then use any program to open the latest files:

```
emacs `latest`
ls `latest`
mv `latest` ../
```

etc.

However, this will break if your file names have spaces or weird characters which is why you [should never parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). A better way would be something like this (add this to your `.bashrc`) :

```
function latest(){
  $1 "$(find . -type f -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2-)"
}
```

This function will execute whatever command you give it as an argument and pass the result of the `find` call (the latest file) to that command. So, you can do things like:

```
latest emacs
latest less
```

If you need to be able to do things like `mv $(latest) foo/` try this one instead:

```
function latest(){
   A=(${@})
   prog=$1;
   lat=$(find . -type f -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2-)
   if [ ! -z $2 ] ; then 
     args=${A[@]:1}; 
     $prog "$lat" "${A[@]:1}"
   else
     $prog "$lat"
   fi
}
```

Then, to copy the latest file to `bar/`, you would do

```
latest cp bar
```

And you can still do `latest emacs` in the same way as before.

Comment: Thank you, there are quite a few things that I can learn here.

Comment: I'd recommend `alias latest='\ls -tr | tail -n 1'` - this will work if you have `ls` aliased.

Answer (score 3):

Since the newest file is also sorted last, you could use `menu-complete-backward`. `menu-complete` and `menu-complete-backward` cycle through completions or insert the first or last completion. I have bound them to option-tab and shift-tab in `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e\t": menu-complete
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

Your terminal emulator might not insert `\e[Z` when you press shift-tab. Use `C-v` or `cat -v` to see what text is inserted when you press a key combination.

Comment: In fact, files are sorted alphabetically, not chronologically. If I figure out how to sort chronologically then I'll update with the info.

Answer (score 2):

The background for the question is the speed of usage. I find a keyboard macro most appropriate. Add to `~/.inputrc`:

```
# Alt-L --> newest file in directory
"\el": "$(ls -t|head -1)"
```

*Further ideas:* Originally, I wanted something that gives me the 1st, 2nd, 3rd newest file. An idea would be, to mark the places with a token, e.g. "grep x _", then execute a keyboard macro "\C-alatest-expansion \C-m" and "latest-expansion" prompts a curses-selection list to pick from the latest files for each " _ " token in the command line.

I consider this an important question, because one remaining advantage of GUI over SHELL is for me the selection of recently used/created files and directories. `autojump` helps a bit for directories, a solution for files is missing.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful. Note that it inserts a literal `$(ls -t|head -1)` into the bash line, so it needs to be interpreted. That makes it less useful, but it is still a nice trick.

Comment: @dotancohen you can avoid that by ending the macro with `\C-e\e` to evaluate the expression. See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666538/127903)

Answer (score 0):

My take on this combines the `find` command of the excellent-as-usual-terdon AA, and the `.inputrc` trick from @weidenrinde, but takes it a bit further:

I have mapped `.,n` to transparently insert the last modified file at the current position in the command line:

```bsh
$ grep .,n ~/.inputrc 
".,n": "\C-u`find . -type f -printf \"%C@ %p\\n\" | sort | tail -n 1 | cut -d \" \" -f 2-`\e\C-e\C-a\C-y\C-e"
```

The trick is to use `\C-e\e` at the end to evaluate the inserted find command in place.

I use `.,` as a prefix for many things, since it's easy to type, and apart from this message never appears in my written text, but you can use whatever.