# How to order files by date in tab completion list

Tags: bash, autocomplete

```
$ 7z l ~/Downloads/Tab
```

How to make the resulting list to be sorted by date, not by name?

I currently use special script to list N most recent files in a given directory (and copy the filename manually into command line), but want to make it seamless and more convenient.

Comment: [Easy in zsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90349/autocomplete-newest-file/90403#90403). I don't know if it's possible in bash.

Comment: Do you want to just see the files listed by date or will you want to somehow add them to the archive in order of date?

Comment: There are many various files in "Downloads" directory, and I want to access the recently downloaded file (maybe unpack it, maybe move somewhere, etc.).

Comment: Maybe fzf and its completion can do it

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `bash` is able to do that, so you might try out `zsh`. I'm not a zsh user though but I think this configuration should work:

```
autoload -U compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' file-sort modification reverse
```

(`reverse` here to see newest files in the end of the list, because the upper part might not be visible on the screen.)

Answer (score -1):

Occasionally I need to find the most recently downloaded file in my Downloads directory but may not know the exact file name.  Here is how I do it.

```
ls -rt ~/Downloads
```

`ls -t` lists the files by time not name, with the most recent being displayed first.  Since my Downloads directory contains so many files I don't want to scroll to the top of the list to see the most recent.  `ls -rt` reverses the order of the list, displaying the most recent file at the bottom of the list.

From there you can do what you need quite easily.  For example:

```
unzip $(ls -rt ~/Downloads | tail -n1)
```

or

```
mv $(ls -rt ~/Downloads | tail -n1) *some_other_location*
```

Your original question could be done like this:

```
7z l $(ls -rt ~/Downloads | tail -n1)
```

I realize this is not adhering to the Tab completion method but it may be suitable for your needs.

Comment: Not saves typing. Actually I alredy have a script `rl` with `ls -lhtc "$@" | head -n $N` do to this.

Comment: The question is how to intergate this or other script into <kbd>Tab</kbd> making think seamless.

Comment: Your snippet also tends to break on some tricky filenames, as typical for downloaded files.

Answer (score -1):

I will do the following steps for it

> ```
>   1. First I will find the files and their timestamps
>   2. Sort them reversely
>   3. Take top N
>   4. Get the filenames
>   5. Zip it or do whatever u like
> ```

And the script looks like this (May be complex)

```
find ~/Downloads/ -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r | head -N | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs 7z l
```

Comment: I already have similar script, named `rl` (recent list). But I need to explicitly call it, then copy&paste. I want it to be more integrated with tab completion.

Answer (score -1):

In bash, you can get something close using, for example,

`7z l ~/Downloads/`<kbd>Alt+n</kbd>

Where `bind` has mapped <kbd>Alt+n</kbd> to a function that rewrites the `READLINE_LINE` variable.

To approximate tab completion, I do this with a argument-parsing-perl-kludge and `fzf` for presenting a menu.

https://github.com/WillForan/fuzzy_arg/blob/master/fuzzy_new_complete.bash